Generalizations of Jordan Curve Theorem
In Dale Rolfsen's Knots and links it is proved that
If $L$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R^2 \backslash L$ has two connected components and $L$ is the boundary of each.
I wonder if the following generalizations are true.

Let $N^2$ be a simply connected and connected $2$-dimensional manifold and $L$ be a closed subset of $N$ which is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R$. I believe that $N \backslash L$ has exactly two connected components and the boundary of each component is $L$.

Let $N^2$ be a connected $2$-dimensional manifold and $L$ be a compact subset of $N$ which is homeomorphic with the unit circle $\mathbb S^1$. I believe that $N \backslash L$ has exactly two connected components and the boundary of each component is $L$.


Are these two generalizations true? Do you know where I can find any proofs?
Thank you.


Let $N^2$ be a simply connected and connected $2$-dimensional manifold and $L$ be a closed subset of $N$ which is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R$. I believe that $N \backslash L$ has exactly two connected components and the boundary of each component is $L$.

$N^2$ here can only be either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $S^2$. In the case of $S^2$ the version of this statement you'd want to be true is that if $L$ is a circle on $S^2$ then $S^2 \setminus L$ has two connected components and the boundary of each component is $L$. By deleting a point this follows from the statement you cited for $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't think $S^2$ even contains any closed subsets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $N^2$ be a connected $2$-dimensional manifold and $L$ be a compact subset of $N$ which is homeomorphic with the unit circle $\mathbb S^1$. I believe that $N \backslash L$ has exactly two connected components and the boundary of each component is $L$.

This is false, and not for Jordan-curve-y reasons either. For example if $N^2$ is the torus $T^2$ and $L$ is, say, the equator, then $T^2 \setminus L$ is connected. I think you need a condition on $L$ involving its image in $\pi_1$ being trivial.

"I don't think $S^2$ even contains any closed subsets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$." You can upgrade this to a definitive "no" by noting that a closed subset of $S^2$ is compact.

Instead of assuming $\pi_1$-triviality, it suffices to assume triviality in $H_1$.

Thank you for your response. I have a more specific question. If $N^2$ is a connected regular surface in $\mathbb R^3$ containing an infinite funnel and $L$ is the boundary of the funnel in $N$, that is $L$ is a circle, does $N \backslash L$ have exactly two connected components?

When you have a specific followup question, the best thing to do is to start a new question, if you can write it well enough. Asking a followup question buried in the comment to an answer to an old question is a sure guarantee that few will ever see your followup question.
